# Calculator Program using JSP AND SERVLET w/o using scripting language(javascript , jquery etc)

Tags: jsp, servlets

Kindly provide me a link or full program about Calculator program using **only jsp and servlet**  , 
**without using any kind of scripting language(javascript,jquery)**.

[image]

Eg. like as shown in diagram in above link , it Should contain 3 textbox as **first no. textbox** , **second no. texbox** and **Result textbox**(where result

should get displayed after calculation).

Enter first number in first no. textbox and second number in second no. texbox

Click on **add** button to display calculated  **addition result** in **Result** textbox and 
thn click on **mulitply** button to display calculated  **multiplication result** in **Result** textbox.

as i new to jsp and servlet ..i didn't get anywhere on net regarding this  tht's why i posted here.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You need to study https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="first">
            <input type="text" name="second">
            <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add">
            <input type="submit" name="multiply" value="Multiply">
        </form>
        Result:${param.add != null?param.first + param.second:param.first * param.second}
    </body>
</html>
```